# Firewall settings with "imagent"

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, firewall

Among others that I recognize, I have the "imagent" been allowed to pass true my firewall (allow incoming connection).

What/who is it, and do I must have it or can I just block it.

I do not remember allowing it in the first place anyway, but that could be due to my age :)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IMAgent is a process that listens for FaceTime/iMessage invitations. It will be active even if FaceTime isn't running. You don't have to block it, but if you don't use FaceTime you can open the application, open preferences, and turn off FaceTime. That should quit the IMAgent process.

Comment: Holly shit!!!  You should have warned me. So, I opened the FaceTime as advised by you, and there was that ugly person staring back at me doing exactly what I was doing!

Answer (score 4):

`imagent` is part of iMessage/Messages/Facetime (see e.g. [here](http://forums.macworld.com/index.php?/topic/134702-what-is-imagent/)) and needs to accept incoming connections for the same reasons as Skype and GoogleTalk do.

Comment: OK, since I do NOT use the "iMessage/Messages/Facetime" I can kill it then.

Answer (score 4):

The top-voted answer should be changed since IMAgent can be used for non-FaceTime messaging purposes. For example, it will connect to your Jabber account if you added one in Messages.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the iMessage system. It's needed when sending messages / pictures.

Answer (score -1):

if it's using too much cpu, feel free to kill. It will be re-launched automatically (and Fans will stop spinning..)