# imagent using significant energy

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

`imagent` (I don't know what this app is, I never downloaded it) is using significant energy.

Whenever I click on the battery icon in the menu bar, it shows that `imagent` is using significant energy:
[image: The image]

I just got this Mac off eBay 2 days ago, and formatted it as soon as i got it.

It's a MacBook Pro 15" 2017 with 16 GB ram, 2.8 GHz i7 and Radeon Pro 555 if that helps.

Comment: Only partially related, but see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86814/firewall-settings-with-imagent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firewall settings with "imagent"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86814/firewall-settings-with-imagent)